# Android GCM Error Notregistered for multiple registrations

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When I send GCM messages to multiple reg_ids some times I get NotRegistered Error.

How can I know which reg_id is not valid

```
{"multicast_id":5825324801553069805,"success":2,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1453198766912894%d41b519ed41b519e"},{"message_id":"0:1453198766913761%d41b519ed41b519e"},{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The response messages have same order with sent data's reg_id order.

As your example, the 3th reg_id is not registered.

```
{
    "multicast_id":5825324801553069805,
    "success":2,
    "failure":1,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[
    {
    "message_id":"0:1453198766912894%d41b519ed41b519e"
    },
    {
    "message_id":"0:1453198766913761%d41b519ed41b519e"
    },
    {
    "error":"NotRegistered"
    }
    ]

}
```